# Cycle two different Win 10 Toast notifications

Tags: python

So my app has a timer that reminds to do something for a few seconds every few minutes. For example it counts down 10 minutes, then for the next 10 seconds I will stretch and the timer will count 10 seconds. When those 10 seconds are up, it resets to 10 minutes again.

So if the first timer runs out, I'd like it to say "it's time to stretch" and show a windows toast notification. After that second timer of 10 seoconds of stretching is up, I want to show another notification that says "ok you can get back to doing whatever you were doing".

Here is the app:

[image]

Here is the code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import itertools

DURATION_INT = 10
toaster = ToastNotifier()
TIME_CYCLER = itertools.cycle([10, 5])  # 10 minutes, 10 seconds
iterToast = itertools.cycle([toaster.show_toast("test1", "test1", duration=3, threaded=True), toaster.show_toast("test2", "test2", duration=3, threaded=True)])

def secs_to_minsec(secs: int):
    mins = secs // 60
    secs = secs % 60
    minsec = f'{mins:02}:{secs:02}'
    return minsec

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.myTimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)

        # App window
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.win = QMainWindow()
        self.win.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
        self.win.setWindowTitle("test")

        # Widgets
        self.titleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.win)
        self.titleLabel.setText("Welcome to my app")
        self.titleLabel.move(50,20)

        self.timerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.win)
        self.timerLabel.move(50,50)
        self.timerLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.timerLabel.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt Helvetica")

        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.win)
        self.startButton.setText("Start")
        self.startButton.move(50,100)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startTimer)

        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.win)
        self.stopButton.setText("Minimize")
        self.stopButton.move(50,130)

        self.update_gui()

        # Show window
        self.win.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def startTimer(self):
        self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)
        self.myTimer.timeout.connect(self.timerTimeout)
        self.myTimer.start(1000)

    def timerTimeout(self):
        self.time_left_int -= 1
        if self.time_left_int == 0:
            next(iterToast)
            # toaster.show_toast("test1", "test1", duration=3, threaded=True)
            self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)

        self.update_gui()

    def update_gui(self):
        minsec = secs_to_minsec(self.time_left_int)
        self.timerLabel.setText(minsec)

    # def minimize():
    #     pass

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = App()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So the problem is that the `cycle` function doesn't work for me. Whenever I run the app, it just shows the first `test1` notification and it repeats every time the clock runs out. It doesn't even cycle through the second notification so I'm thinking `itertools` might not be what I'm looking for.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution. `itertools` isn't applicable in my case I believe but I created a new variable `self.current_timer = 1` inside of my class and changed this function to look like this:

```py
    def timerTimeout(self):
        self.time_left_int -= 1
        if self.time_left_int == 0:
            if self.current_timer == 1:
                toaster.show_toast("test1", "test1", duration=3, threaded=True)
                self.current_timer = 2
            elif self.current_timer == 2:
                toaster.show_toast("test2", "test2", duration=3, threaded=True)
                self.current_timer = 1
            self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)

        self.update_gui()
```

So eventually, I manually set the variable to be whatever I need it to be for each notificaiton.